# Generating Pojos from XSD with JAXB while a element and a attribute have the same name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

My Sample XSD file is this:
http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/geometryPrimitives.xsd

Im using Netbeans 7.3.1 and im trying to generate a Pojo from it but it says :

```
[ERROR] Property"Rows"is already defined.Use<jaxb:property>to resolve this conflict.
   Line 653 of http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/geometryPrimitives.xsd
```

i dont understand the JAXB external binding with an .xjb file. Is Netbeans able to build it? Are there any aids from Netbeans to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You propably have to tell the XJC compiler to use different names for the attribute and the element, see other question here

[JAXB - Property "Value" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this)