# Property "Any" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict

Tags: java, xml, web-services, maven, jaxb

I'm trying to use CXF to consume a SOAP web service. The issue I'm having is that JAXB throws up when trying to consume the WSDL. The part it doesn't like is:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax"/>
    <xs:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

It gives the error:

> Property "Any" is already defined. Use `<jaxb:property>` to resolve this conflict.

From reading other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this) one, it is possible to define an external binding file to resolve the error. The issue is I'm not sure how to do this within the `cxf-codegen-plugin`. Can anyone point me at how to do it?

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/DataGeneratorInbox.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Ps. wsdl is fixed. I dont have the option of changing it to something more sensible

Comment: Can you share your binding file?

Comment: Not really i'm afraid. Left the company quite a while ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is I'm not sure how to do this within the `cxf-codegen-plugin`. Can anyone point me at how to do it?

You can add binding files in the `cxf-codegen-plugin` with the [`<bindingFiles>`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html#Mavencxf-codegen-plugin%28WSDLtoJava%29-Example1:PassinginaJAX-WSBindingfile) attribute, like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/DataGeneratorInbox.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile><!-- path to your file --></bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @Tom Squires, I am also facing the same issue. I tried to write the binding file but still facing some issues. Can any one please provide the binding file for this.?

Comment: @Amar You're not commenting to the right person, but take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this) for the binding file.