# "WSDL" schema type is "experimental and not supported" by JAXB RI error

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I'm tring to adding a wsdl service to my trial new java project. When I press right click on the project name and select new - > web service client. Then, I uploaded my wsdl file. Then it gave me an error message. Property "Any is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to solve this conflict.

[image]

Then, I searched that error and I found some result about adding binding for two property with the same name.

I followed that link. 
[Binding WSDL to Java with JAXB](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/websvc/jaxb.html)

And again, I pressed right click on the project name and select new - > jaxb binding. Then, this time, it showed me another error like that. 
"WSDL" schema type is "experimental and not supported" by JAXB RI.

[image]

But, I couldn't figure out that error.

In addition, I'm working with Netbeans 7.4

My wsdl service have multiple repetitions like following any-any sample.

```
<s:element name="xxxResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xxxResult">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
                  <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
```

Can anybody help me for these problems?

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this

Comment: My project couldn't generate cxf-servlet.xjb file or binding.xml. It gave error as I mentioned in the title. @fg78nc

Comment: Can you provide your WSDL?

Comment: I added it to my questions @fg78nc

Comment: I don't see WSDL in your question.

Comment: I couldn't share all file. The file belongs to my company @fg78nc