# xsd conflict when using jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm trying to revive a legacy project for my client. The project is pretty old and it uses the jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate some java classes from an xsd schema file.

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <goals>
               <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
         <sources>
            <source>src/main/resources/custom-api.xsd</source>
         </sources>
         <packageName>com.client</packageName>
         <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

The problem is the company doesn't allow any internet access - hence when I generate the code I get errors such as `java.net.UnknownHostException` saying that it cannot find `www.springframework.org`.

So I understand that the solution for this problem is to provide the xsd files locally - which I did, extracting them in a folder named `import` and I created also a `catalog.cat` file to rewrite the access to those xsd files to the `import` folder.

The `catalog.cat` file looks like this:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd" "import/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd" "import/mule.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/schemadoc/3.4/mule-schemadoc.xsd" "import/mule-schemadoc.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd" "import/mule-jms.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd" "import/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd" "import/spring-tool-3.1.xsd"
```

Unfortunately I get some conflicts in `spring-beans.xsd`:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2publicId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd; lineNumber: 566; columnNumber: 30; Property "Ref" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
                at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:56)
```

I suspect that this happens because the xsd is loaded multiple times - probably being referenced by other xsd files. The usual way to get rid of such conflicts is to use a binding file, but I don't think this is the right thing to do considering that this is a third party xsd file.

An example of a sample project has been provided here: https://github.com/scutaru/sample-xjc

Anybody knows how I can get rid of these conflicts ?

Comment: I just tagged this question with maven-jaxb2-plugin because I changed the plugin from jaxb2-maven-plugin to maven-jaxb2-plugin and I get the same result. I even have a small sample project that can be used to reproduce the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAXB - Property "Value" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this)

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded your project sample (thanks for it by the way)

- After upgrading to latest version of `maven-jaxb2-plugin` with new coordinates

```xml
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.9</version>
```

- And after updating your catalog to fix the public ref to namespace declaration

```
PUBLIC "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" "maven:org.springframework:spring-beans::!/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" "maven:org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar::!/META-INF/mule.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/schemadoc" "maven:org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar::!/META-INF/mule-schemadoc.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" "maven:org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jms:jar::!/META-INF/mule-jms.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" "maven:org.springframework:spring-context::!/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool" "maven:org.springframework:spring-beans::!/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd"
```

I manage to reproduce your error

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans{566,30}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Property "Ref" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error (ErrorReceiver.java:56)
[...]
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans{606,48}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: The following location is relevant to the above error
```

As you can see, the error is split in two parts, in order to know where the conflict is located. Here for example, you have the `ref` element that is declared twice in `spring-beans.xsd` (line 566 v. line 606).

By looking at the xsd, you'll find that `constructor-arg` `xsd:element` has two `ref` declared, one as child `xsd:element` and another one as `xsd:attribute`, documented as `A short-cut alternative to a nested "<ref bean='...'/>" element.`

In the end, your configuration is good but you need to apply the [following trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this) that was mentionned in the comments.

Using the following `bindings.xjb` file, you should be able to generate your XSD :

```xml
<jaxb:bindings 
    version="2.1"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:bindings xmlns:tns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" scd="x-schema::tns">
        <jaxb:bindings scd="/tns:ref">
            <jaxb:property name="refAttribute"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings scd="/tns:value">
            <jaxb:property name="valueAttribute"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings scd="/tns:key">
            <jaxb:property name="keyAttribute"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings xmlns:tns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" scd="x-schema::tns">
        <jaxb:bindings scd="/tns:property-placeholder">
            <jaxb:class name="org.springframework.schema.context.PropertyPlaceholderElement"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```